# Impossible to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb

Been downloading Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS multiple times already.
Don't have a CD drive and created a bootable USB stick with recommended UUI from "Pendrivelinux.com
Once rebooting, Windows XP starts as usual. Pressing F12 on multiple occasions does not work either. Trying different ports also ain't working.
Tried installing "CD Boot helper" and getting error message every single time.
All I want to do is get rid of my Windows and install Ubuntu! Is there a way that works?

Comment: You should try this USB on another computer. If it boots there, try to press [F8] or [Del] (or [F2] on some machines) and set up booting from USB.

Comment: Do you have BIOS or EFI? Have you changed your boot order? Most importantly, what is the error you keep getting?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your USB stick, boot and enter BIOS with the USB still in.

Go to "boot" menu and you should be able to see your USB stick there. Move it to the top of the list, save and boot.

If you don't see your USB stick in BIOS check under hard disks. Some bioses treat a USB stick as an alternative hard drive. Again, move your USB to the top and boot.